# how to retrieve class over web service?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I have a "User" class in both my Web App and my Webservice.

Everything works and I get data back but when I assign the User class in my Web App that of the Web Service then it cannot convert between the two

How I call it in my web app

```
 User user = new User();
        user = userService.Login(UserName.Text, Password.Text); // Here it says it can't convert
```

how I send it from my web service

```
[WebMethod]
    public User Login (string userName, string Password)
    {
        UserData usrData = new UserData();
        return usrData.UserExists(userName, Password); 
    }
```

And what my class looks like in both the Web App and the Web Service

```
[Serializable]
public class User
{
    /// <summary>
    /// User Id
    /// </summary>
    public int ID { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// User Name
    /// </summary>
    public string Name { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// User Surname
    /// </summary>
    public string Surname { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// User Email
    /// </summary>
    public string Email { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// User Password
    /// </summary>
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: How about something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/560722/asmx-web-service-expose-class?

Answer (score 1):

So you're trying to call it from C# code? Simply do this...

```
User user = userService.Login(UserName.Text, Password.Text);
```

If you're calling it from the server side, you can remove the `[WebMethod]` attribute. You don't even need a Web Service for this, assuming `userService` is of type `UserService`, just place the `UserService.cs` class inside your `App_Code` folder. Or better yet, place `UserService` class in a class library, and add a reference in your web application to that library.

Comment: Trying what your are saying there is exactly whats the problem. It can't convert the user in the service to the user in the app because of the different namespaces. Also my userService is my own service that I created to handle input between the user and the service.

Comment: @JcMey3r In that case, you need to update your question so that it clearly describes your situation. You did not describe different namespaces or how your web service is separated from your web application.

Comment: I did mention that I have exactly the same class in the Web service and the actual web app so that would give the 2 differences in namespaces.

Comment: @JcMey3r You have not properly fleshed out your question. You have not described the structure of your web service (which is a very generic term by the way) and how it relates to your website. And no, having the same class in the web service and the "actual web app" doesn't automatically mean they have different namespaces. What you **should do** is have the class in a [Class Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d11h6832(v=vs.71).aspx) and then reference it from both projects. If you're using a service reference to your web service then check the box to reuse classes when consuming